# AutoCAD Map/Civil 3D Feature Data Object (FDO) layer displays but is no longer editable

Tags: layers, editing, sql-server, feature-layer, autocad-map

Just over a week ago, one of our main GIS layers became uneditable. Our GIS layers are connected to AutoCAD Civil 3D (Fig.3) via an SQL Server Spatial Connection in the Task Pane. We were able to edit all connected layers for years, until last week when Cadastre became read only within AutoCAD Civil 3D. All other Feature Data Object (FDO) layers remained editable (Fig.1), while Cadastre is only visible and selectable (Fig.2).

What we know up to this point:

- Cadastre is selectable but cannot be edited in AutoCAD Civil 3D
- All other layers can be selected and edited in AutoCAD Civil 3D
- DB Admin reported no locks or unusual activity on the Cadastre table
- All layers, including Cadastre, are editable in another application - QGIS
- Cadastre table was reconnected several times in AutoCAD Civil 3D
- This affects all users using AutoCAD Civil 3D on separate workstations
- All users have the same edit permissions to the Cadastre table in the database

Can you help us resolve this issue?

**Fig.1** - Other layer objects present edit grips when selecting them.

[image]

**Fig.2** - Cadastre can be selected but no edit grips presented. No edit commands or function are available for this layer.

[image]

**Fig.3** - AutoCAD Civil 3D version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems the table in question was recreated at some point and the "Primary Key" value was omitted from the PK column, which was set to an "Identity" column type. After recreating the Cadastre table with the correct column type and value of "Identity" and "Primary Key" respectively, AutoCAD now permits edits.